# Count of repeated characters including the non-repeated ones in a string python

Tags: python, sorting, count

I am need to find the count of repeated character by groups of letters
for e.g if I have a string, `s = "hggdsaajhjhajadj"`, then I need the counts as

> h-1, g-2, d-1, s-1, a-2, j-1, h-1 and so on

and not {'a': 4, 'd': 2, 'g': 2, 'h': 3, 'j': 4, 's': 1}

The following code gives me the counts by letter.

```
s = "hggdsaajhjhajadj"
def find_repeated(string):
    table = {}
    for char in string.lower():
        if char in table:
            table[char] += 1
        elif char != " ":
            table[char] = 1
        else:
            table[char] = 0
    return table

print find_repeated(s)
```

> {'a': 4, 'd': 2, 'g': 2, 'h': 3, 'j': 4, 's': 1}

If I try with the following,

```
 for c in sorted(set(s)):
       i = 1; 
       while c * i in s:
           i += 1
       print c, "-", i - 1
```

Then, I get the following:

> a - 2 d - 1 g - 2 h - 1 j - 1 s - 1

Can you please provide me some idea how I solve

Comment: This sounds like Run Length Encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function does what you specified:

```
def mycount(s):
        i = 0
        res = []
        while i<len(s):
                j = i+1
                while j<len(s) and s[i] == s[j]:
                        j += 1
                res.append( (s[i],j-i) )
                i = j
        return res
```

Answer (score 3):

Python's tool for dealing with contiguous groups is [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = "hggdsaajhjhajadj"
>>> [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(s)]
[('h', 1), ('g', 2), ('d', 1), ('s', 1), ('a', 2), ('j', 1), ('h', 1), ('j', 1), ('h', 1), ('a', 1), ('j', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('j', 1)]
```

`groupby` returns an object which if you iterate over, you get the key and an iterator over the group elements:

```
>>> grouped = groupby(s)
>>> for key, group in grouped:
...     print(key, list(group))
...     
h ['h']
g ['g', 'g']
d ['d']
s ['s']
a ['a', 'a']
j ['j']
h ['h']
j ['j']
h ['h']
a ['a']
j ['j']
a ['a']
d ['d']
j ['j']
```